# How can I sort a JSON file by an attribute in asec order?

Tags: java, json, api, jackson, jq

I have two JSON files to compare, and one of the outputs isn't in the right order. In order to compare a json file with another,
I need to sort it by the name attribute. However, I encountered many difficulties. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Or Is there any way to sort the JsonFile 1 by attribute "name" is ascending order ( Expected output- JsonFile2)

I tried with jq -s .Json.json > out.json, No outputs. can I know how to pass thee jq to sort by attribute name ?

**JsonFile1**:

```json
{
  "responseStatus": "SUCCESS",
  "data": {
    "name": "reusable_text__v",
    "object": "annotation_keywords__sys",
    "label": "Reusable Text",
    "label_plural": "Reusable Text",
    "active": true,
    "additional_type_validations": [],
    "type_fields": [{
        "required": true,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "reusable_text_content__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "reusable_text_type__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "source_text_asset__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "country__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "create_from_annotation_id__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "create_from_annotation_source__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "product__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "id"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "name__v"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "status__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "created_by__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "created_date__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "modified_by__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "modified_date__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "global_id__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "link__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "object_type__v"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "lifecycle__v"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "state__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "create_from_annotation_source_unbound__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "state_stage_id__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "stage__sys"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**JsonFile2**: (I need to sort previous json format by the name attribute in ascending order)

```json
{
  "responseStatus": "SUCCESS",
  "data": {
    "name": "reusable_text__c",
    "object": "annotation_keywords__sys",
    "label": "Reusable Text Asset",
    "label_plural": "Reusable Text Assets",
    "active": true,
    "additional_type_validations": [],
    "type_fields": [{
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "id"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "object_type__v"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "name__v"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "status__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "created_by__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "created_date__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "modified_by__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "modified_date__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "global_id__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "link__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "lifecycle__v"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "state__v"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "match_text__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "state_stage_id__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "stage__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "reusable_text_content__c"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "create_from_annotation_source__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "create_from_annotation_id__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "reusable_text_type__c"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "country__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "product__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "create_from_annotation_source_unbound__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "source_text_asset__c"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried `JsonArray` and `JsonObject`, but did not succeed in finding the correct solution

Comment: Do you have a java bean for this data

Comment: Why do you want to sort a json? you can compare by attribute instead by order. You can specify the specific order you receive a json with an annotation. But its easier doing it by attribute

Comment: @Cayman I have written an automation script to compare results from different environments, not just this JSON. In order to compare the JSON, I need to write my script in a generic way. As you said, I can compare by attribute, but I need to compare all the json data in any format, and it's not possible to change the json format in the code.

Comment: @DavidKariuki Nope

Comment: If it's not only Java code, then jq might help. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/.
Search for `sort`

Comment: @ShaharT  Thanks . I tried with jq -s .Json.json > out.json, No outputs. can I know how to pass thee jq to sort by attribute name

Comment: Confused. If one were to sort the JsonFile 1 by attribute "name" in ascending order, I don't think the expected output would look like JsonFile2. Also, there are "name" attributes at two levels, but assuming you mean the `type_fields` array, your JsonFile2 target example is also not sorted by "name".

Comment: @VivekaRaja Can you please explain how your desired sorting should change the content of `.data.name` from `reusable_text__v` to `reusable_text__c`, the value of `.data.label` from `Reusable Text` to `Reusable Text Asset`, and the value of `.data.label_plural` from `Reusable Text` to `Reusable Text Assets`?

Comment: @qmacro you're correct. I need to sort by name of type_fields

Comment: @pmf Correct pmf, that I got from another environment. Please forget about json 2 .If I could sort the json1 file by attribute name in type_fields, will help to compare using my automation code

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array located at `.data.type_fields` by its  object items' field `.name` using `sort_by` and the update operator `|=`.

```sh
jq '.data.type_fields |= sort_by(.name)' JsonFile1 > JsonFile2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YNMTg4rgAr)

However, when sorting your sample `JsonFile1` that way, the resulting JSON does not look like your sample `JsonFile2`.

```json
{
  "responseStatus": "SUCCESS",
  "data": {
    "name": "reusable_text__v",
    "object": "annotation_keywords__sys",
    "label": "Reusable Text",
    "label_plural": "Reusable Text",
    "active": true,
    "additional_type_validations": [],
    "type_fields": [
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "country__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "create_from_annotation_id__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "create_from_annotation_source__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "create_from_annotation_source_unbound__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "created_by__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "created_date__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "global_id__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "id"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "lifecycle__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "link__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "modified_by__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "modified_date__v"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "name__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "object_type__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "product__v"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "reusable_text_content__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "reusable_text_type__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "source_text_asset__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "stage__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "custom",
        "name": "state__v"
      },
      {
        "required": false,
        "source": "system",
        "name": "state_stage_id__sys"
      },
      {
        "required": true,
        "source": "standard",
        "name": "status__v"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , It will infidelity helps me to resolve this issue. but i'm getting the following error while run this in command line - error 'sort_by' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Any suggestion please?

Comment: @VivekaRaja In which OS and shell are you trying to run `jq`? Are you using [stedolan/jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)? Which version? `jq --version`

Comment: I installed using chocolatey command line stedolan/jq and the current version is jq-1.6. It works now by using powershell . Thank you so much Pmf . I will find the way how to save the sort json by coding